# Google Cloud Platform - Regex for metric

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm sending data to GCP with this format:

t,26.40;h,42.60;c,3.68;n,0.32;s,216

The letters mean:
t- Temperature
h- humidity
c- CO
n- NO2
s- sound

To create the metrics in the GCP (to use it on the stackdriver), I need a regular expression to get the values that I want. I want to create a metric for each value. What should be the regex for the values that I want? Per example, the regex for "26.40" is different for the "42.60"... I have no idea about regex rules... I can modify the format that I'm sending data easily (at least I think). Any help would be perfect!

PS: Google Cloud Platform uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

This will match the line you've provided:

`t,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);h,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);c,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);n,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);s,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

If you're not always going to have those letters in that order, try this and iterate through multiple matches:

`([a-z]),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately, the `\G` (continue) operator is not supported in re2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm used to PCRE. It should still work for this just by removing the `\G`, it'll just also match stuff like `c,26.40;some other text,42.60` if that's a concern. I've edited out the `\G` from the start of the second example.

Comment: @EthanJ. Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! Just one more question please, imagine that my output is that (with units associated): t,26.40 ºC;h,42.60 %(HR);c,3.68 ppm;n,0.32 ppm;s,216 dB        What do I need to get, per example the "26.40 ºC"? Because, ºC has different characters from %(HR) and ppm and dB... How do I do in that case? Again, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Marco, just add a `.+?` immediately before each `;`. This is a non-greedy match for any characters other than newlines, so they'll work well enough to match the space and the few characters before each semicolon. Or, use the second example, which works regardless. Do you need to match the units or just account for them while matching the numbers?

Comment: @EthanJ.I did it in two ways: 1st: c,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).+?; This one didn't work and I tried this 2nd: c,(\d+(?:\.\d+).+?);  With this one I get the text that I want "marked" but with one warning "The extracted value need to be "DOUBLE" type" :/